# How to uniquely identify an email with IMAP?

Tags: email, imap

I'm trying to receive and process mails by querying them with IMAP from a mail server. I need guaranteed at-most-once processing. Therefore, I need to be able to detect what mails I have already processed.

The IMAP Unique ID cannot serve that purpose because it's validity might change. If that happens I have no way of relating already processed UIDs to the new UIDs that I'm seeing after the change.

**How can I uniquely identify messages and achieve at-most-once processing?**

In fact, how are mail clients such as Outloook doing this? If the validity changes they must be able to relate the locally stored mails to the new UIDs.

Comment: In practise the uidvalidity does not change.  It generally only does under exceptional circumstances, or if it is a new incarnation of a folder with the same name.

Comment: Real clients: if the uidvalidity changes, they resync the folder from scratch, removing their local state.

Comment: Have you considered moving processed messages to another IMAP folder? [or setting custom flag]

Comment: Very useful comments, thanks. I might go for one of those approaches. I'm now investigating deduplication by hash as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37774853/can-we-deduplicate-emails-retrieved-through-imap-by-hash